# Grouped UITableView scrollToRow not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm using `UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)` with multiple sections and dynamic heights of cells. Each section has a header.

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of the table view

```swift
let lastSection = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection) - 1, section: lastSection)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

My problem is:

when there is **only one item in the section**, the table view gets scrolled to the header instead of the item. When there is more than one item everything works well.

Additionally for the `plain` style of table view, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection` was not precise enough. Even though I don't use dynamic heights for the section headers.

So the final fix is: use the same values in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)` and `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { 
    let lastSection = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection) - 1, section: lastSection)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.